# CSS - focus is not working outside the div in html

Tags: html, css

```css
input[type=text] {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: width .35s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  //width: 250px;
}

.form {
  padding: 2%
}

.form-group {
  background-color: orange
}

.form-groupText {
  background-color: red;
  display: none
}

.form-group:focus+.form-groupText {
  display: block;
}

.form-test {
  background-color: purple;
  display: block
}

.form-group:focus+.form-test {
  display: block;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<h1>The width Property</h1>

<p>Set the width of the input field to 100 pixels. However, when the input field gets focus, make it 250 pixels wide:</p>

<div data-value="brand" class="form">
  <h2 class="">This is a heading in a div element</h2>
  <input class='form-group' type="text" name="search">
  <h2 class="form-groupText">search for Fruits</h2>
</div>

<h2 class="form-test">search for Veggies</h2>
```

when we focus on input box, then only we have to show these two - **search for Fruits** and **search for Veggies**

however **search for Fruits** is shown when we have focus on input tag

**search for Veggies** is shown always, can we show **search for Veggies** only when focused on inout

Comment: You might want to start by looking up what `+` actually means in CSS.

Comment: and where is your js in this code? since you tagged js in your question

Comment: @ChrisG thanks, this has only html & css,

Comment: @Quentin thanks, can we achieve this using css and html ?

Comment: @srikanth there are some weird things there when trying to match your words with the code shown.. anyway as long as you were expecting to hide those "search for..." and show both only when the input control has focus, you should put both those `<h2>` (as display none by default) in the same container after the input and use the `~` combinator instead of `+` to turn them to display block.

Comment: @srikanth — I'd throw out the existing code, the markup really doesn't make a lot of sense, and implement my business logic in JS not CSS.